# CSS Dropdown: child div top offset same as parent height?

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu

I am working on a (CSS) dropdown menu, which consists of a span element (parent) and a ul inside of it (child, the actual dropdown). The parent is a relative positioned block element; the child has absolute positioning in order to be displayed beneath it's parent.

Now I need the child dropdown always to be shown below the parent. However, I'd rather not give the child a fixed top offset (ie. the height of the parent element). The child may have a variable height, I dont want to rely on a fixed height. Is there any way to do this without the need of additional Javascript?

The HTML looks like this:

```
<span class="dropdown demo" data-dropdown-trigger="click"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i> 20 results per page
    <ul class="list">
        <li><a href="javascript:;">10 results</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;">20 results</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;">50 results</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;">100 results</a></li>
    </ul>
</span>
```

The CSS:

```
span.demo {
    width:150px;
    margin:50px 0 0 50px;
}

span.dropdown {
-webkit-user-select: none;  
   -moz-user-select: none;    
    -ms-user-select: none;      
        user-select: none;
    position:relative;
    font-size:11px;
    display:block;
    color:#000;
    padding:5px;
    border-radius:2px;
    border:1px solid #FFF;
    font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    cursor:pointer;
}
span.dropdown.show {
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    cursor:default;
}
span.dropdown a {
    outline:0;
}
span.dropdown ul.list {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:23px;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    background:#FFF;
    box-shadow:2px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    color:#000;
    list-style:none;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius:3px;
    z-index:5;
}
span.dropdown.show ul.list {
    display:block;
}
span.dropdown ul.list li a {
    color:#31357F;
    display:block;
    float:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:5px;
    text-decoration:none;
    background:#FFF;
    text-align:left;
    margin:0;
}
span.dropdown ul.list li a:hover {
    color:#FFF;
    background:#217ba4;
}
```

I left the Javascript out, which takes care of toggeling the dropdown. You can check it out on [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cbernardini/odyuv7jd/). Basically, I want to get rid of top: 23px in span.dropdown ul.list. Changing it to bottom:0; makes it drop over the parent.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.fn.dropdown = function(){
        var cfg = {
            ddclass: '.dropdown',
            delayout: 700
        };
        var dd = $(this),
            ev = dd.data('dropdown-trigger'),
            t;
        switch (ev) {
            default:
                dd.on('mouseover mouseout', function(e){
                    $(cfg.ddclass).removeClass('show');
                    dd.toggleClass('show', (e.type == 'mouseover'));
                });
            break;
            case "click":
                dd.on('click', function(){
                    dd.toggleClass('show', !dd.hasClass('show'));
                });
                $(document).on('mouseup', function(e){
                    if (!dd.is(e.target) && dd.has(e.target).length === 0) {
                        dd.removeClass('show');
                    }
                });
                if (!dd.data('dropdown-persistent')) {
                    dd.on('mouseout', function(){
                        t = setTimeout(function(){
                            if (dd.is(':visible')) dd.removeClass('show');
                        }, cfg.delayout);
                    }).on('mouseover', function(){
                        if (t) clearTimeout(t);
                    });
                } 
            break;
        }
    };
    $('.dropdown').each(function(){
        $(this).dropdown('.dropdown');
    });
});
```

```css
span.demo {
    width:150px;
    margin:50px 0 0 50px;
}

span.dropdown {
-webkit-user-select: none;  
   -moz-user-select: none;    
    -ms-user-select: none;      
        user-select: none;
    position:relative;
    font-size:11px;
    display:block;
    color:#000;
    padding:5px;
    border-radius:2px;
    border:1px solid #FFF;
    font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    cursor:pointer;
}
span.dropdown.show {
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    cursor:default;
}
span.dropdown a {
    outline:0;
}
span.dropdown ul.list {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:23px;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    background:#FFF;
    box-shadow:2px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    color:#000;
    list-style:none;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius:3px;
    z-index:5;
}
span.dropdown.show ul.list {
    display:block;
}
span.dropdown ul.list li a {
    color:#31357F;
    display:block;
    float:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:5px;
    text-decoration:none;
    background:#FFF;
    text-align:left;
    margin:0;
}
span.dropdown ul.list li a:hover {
    color:#FFF;
    background:#217ba4;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="dropdown demo" data-dropdown-trigger="click"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i> 20 results per page
    <ul class="list">
        <li><a href="javascript:;">10 results</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;">20 results</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;">50 results</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;">100 results</a></li>
    </ul>
</span>
```

Comment: `span` tags should not contain block level elements. Regardless, `top:100%` should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of a px value use:

```
span.dropdown ul.list {
    top:100%;
}
```

[JSfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cbernardini/odyuv7jd/)

Comment: Thank you, hadn't thought of this possibility yet. Works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You really shouldn't place div inside span, it's incorrect. But anyway, the solution of your problem is simple, just replace 25px with 100% in span.dropdown ul.list

```
display:none;
position:absolute;
top:100%;
width:100%;
background:#FFF;
box-shadow:2px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
padding:0;
margin:0;
color:#000;
list-style:none;
border:1px solid #ccc;
border-radius:3px;
z-index:5;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/odyuv7jd/2/

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will replace the span with a div.